# aws spot block instance stuck on capacity-not-available

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I recently started to use spot block instances because it is guaranteed for a certain hours.

When I send the request with on-demand price as max price with a few hours block time, the request stuck on capacity-not-available status all the time.

I keep trying from around noon till evening, the request stays at capacity-not-available status.

Then I tried to request for regular spot instances with same parameters, the request got fulfilled immediately.

Does anyone know if this behavior is reasonable? If it is true, I don't see much value in spot block instances then.

I use us-west-2 region by the way.

Thanks everyone for your advice in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-bid-status.html

```
Holding:
If one or more request constraints are valid but can't be met yet, 
or if there is not enough capacity, the request goes into a holding
state waiting for the constraints to be met. 
The request options affect the likelihood of the request being fulfilled. 
For example, if you specify a maximum price below the current Spot price, 
your request stays in a holding state until the Spot price goes below
your maximum price. If you specify an Availability Zone group,
the request stays in a holding state until the Availability Zone constraint is met.
```

Maybe you could try another availability zone?

Also you could check the current prices on https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot/pricing/ to see if your bid is in range.

Comment: Thank you! I tried in us-west-1 and it got fulfilled immediately. That's sad because us-west-1 does not have EFS. I'll take a look how to mount EFS across regions

Comment: What about selecting another availability zone rather then another region?

Comment: @RongShen officially, EFS doesn't work across regional boundaries.  You have to use something like [my workaround](https://serverfault.com/a/799213/153161) which requires a small instance running HAProxy in the EFS region.  You then use that instance's IP address as the mount target, after configuring VPC Peering between the regions.  Remember that data transfer between regions is not entirely free.  Between us-west-1 and us-west-2, it's $0.02 per GB transferred.  EFS works great with this solution, but you will notice the impact of distance on latency.

Comment: Also, a good bet for available capacity and good spot prices is currently us-east-2, which does have EFS.

Comment: @jarnohenneman that's a great suggestion. My test shows selecting all availability zone works too

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks a lot for the workaround! I did not find any good way to mount EFS across regions. Your way is a life saver